# Log Data Sent from RFDuino

Tags: ios, objective-c, arduino, rfduino

My RFDuino is sending data every 2 seconds.

I can see what's being sent via the Arduino Serial manager but I'd like to log this out in Xcode.

What method do I need to use to NSLog this?

Answer (score 0):

Set RFDuinoDelegate to your view.
DidReceive method should be called automatically with the data been sent from the rfduino

Example here with receiving string data in Swift

```
func didReceive(data: NSData!) {

    var stringData: String = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as! String
}
```